# Splitting read & write to redis with nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, replication, node-redis, redis-cluster

I have setup redis on three seperate instances and have configured them in such a way that 1 instance is a master and 2 are replicas of master. I have used sentinels to make sure there is high availability of the setup. I have a nodejs application which needs to use the redis. How do i achieve the read and write splitting in my application as incase my redis master goes down one of my read replica becomes the master and the writes need to go to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far has I know, [`ioredis`](https://github.com/luin/ioredis#sentinel) is the only node redis client that supports sentinels.

> "ioredis guarantees that the node you connected to is always a master even after a failover. When a failover happens, instead of trying to reconnect to the failed node (which will be demoted to slave when it's available again), ioredis will ask sentinels for the new master node and connect to it. All commands sent during the failover are queued and will be executed when the new connection is established so that none of the commands will be lost."

Comment: I have the same question with sentinel : can ioredis split the read & write traffic with sentinel ?